# Why does python return index 0 if the item is 0 for the .index method?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing

[ss]https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrKwz.png

howdy guys, 
I wrote a list

```
l = [0, 0, 0, 1]
```

and asked Python to print the index for every item, like this

```
for i in l:
   print(l.index(i))
```

It returns

```
0
0
0
3
```

Notice how it returns 0 for all the elements that are 0 but returns the correct index when the item is 1. 
   Similarly,

```
l2 = [0, 0, 3, 2, 5]
for i in l2:
   print(l2.index(i))
# returns 0, 0, 2, 3, 4

l3 = [2, 3, 4, 0, 0]
for i in l3:
   print(l3.index(i))
# returns 0, 1, 2, 3, 3. what?
```

But

```
l4 = [1, 2, 0, 3, 4]
for i in l4:
   print(l4.index(i))
# returns 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

It seems that the loop goes wacky as soon as there are two elements in a row that are 0. Is there a name for this or an explanation? Did I write the code wrong?

Comment: I assume your first list should be `l = [0, 0, 0, 1]` instead of a zero at the end?

Comment: _"list.index(x[, start[, end]]) - Return zero-based index in the list of the first item whose value is equal to x."_ - it does what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Your screen shot shows ```l = [0,0,0,1]``` and you have given ```l=[0,0,0,0]```

Comment: Oh my bad! you're right i'll fix that

Comment: `index` returns *only* the *first* position in the list that matches the element given. `index` does as intended here

Comment: What is 'wacky'?

Comment: I believe index only returns the first match. That's why don't get what you expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it wrong. If you try:

```
l = [2, 2, 2, 1]

for i in l:
   print(l.index(i))
```

you will also get:

```
0
0
0
3
```

That is because during the ierations, you tell python to print the index of `0` three times. Python will only print the first index it sees that equal to what was specified.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html),

list.index(x[, start[, end]])
returns "zero-based index in the list **of the first item** whose value is equal to x".

So, if there are two or more elements with the same value in your list, you will get always the index of the first occurence. In other words your code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the index and item of a list while iterating over each entry you can try either of the below 2 options -

Option 1:

`for i in range(len(l)):
     print(i)`

Option 2:

```
for i,v in enumerate(l):
     print(i)
```

Both the above options will give you the result 0 1 2 3